# PHP Slim 4 HttpNotFoundException -- Routes not found when moving application to live server

Tags: php, slim

I have a WordPress website that I have extended with the `Slim Framework` to provide some custom API. Everything works fine in local, but when I move the application on a live server (SiteGround), if I try to call any of the custom endpoints I get a `404 error Slim\Exception\HttpNotFoundExceptio`.

This is my folder structure

In Local the `root` folder is `C:\xampp\htdocs\example\`

In remote the `root` folder is `/home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/`

```
api\
  vendor\
  public\
    .htaccess
    index.php
  routes\
    v1\
      autocomplete.php
  .htaccess
  composer.json
  composer.lock
wp-admin
wp-content
wp-includes
... all others WordPress files
```

In local I was able to call the endpoint `http://localhost/example/api/v1/autocomplete`, while on remote if I call `https://www.example.com/api/v1/autocomplete` I get a `404 not found error`

```
code: 404
file: "/home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php"
line: 91
message: "Not found."
type: "Slim\Exception\HttpNotFoundException"
```

As per [Slim documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/start/web-servers.html#apache-configuration) the Apache `mod_rewrite` is enabled by the default WordPress `.htaccess` and `AllowOverride All` is [setted by default on all SiteGround server](https://www.siteground.com/kb/is_it_possible_to_set_apaches_allowoverride_directive_to_all/).

Here is the content of the important Slim files

root\api\.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

root\api\public\.htaccess

```
# Redirect to front controller
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

root\api\public\index.php

```
<?php
use Selective\BasePath\BasePathMiddleware;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require_once __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";

$app = AppFactory::create();

// Add Slim routing middleware
$app->addRoutingMiddleware();

// Set the base path to run the app in a subdirectory.
// This path is used in urlFor().
$app->add(new BasePathMiddleware($app));

$app->addErrorMiddleware(true, true, true);
 
// PUT ALL ROUTES HERE
require_once "../routes/v1/autocomplete.php";

// Run app
$app->run();
```

root\api\routes\v1\autocomplete.php

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;

$app->get("/v1/autocomplete", function (Request $request, Response $response) {
  $params = $request->getQueryParams();
  $payload = array(
    "status" => "error",
    "message" => "missing param 'user_input'",
  );
  if (isset($params["user_input"])) {
    $payload = getSuggestions($params);
  }
  $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($payload));
  return $response
    ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please show as at least one of your api route definition.

Comment: Hi @odan I have updated the question with one of the custom api.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your Slim 4 app in a sub-directory of the webservers DocumentRoot, you need to set the basePath.

Maybe in your case:

```php
$app->setBasePath('/api');
```

Comment: You're right, I had to set the basePath and disable the BasePathMiddleware. I thought the middleware set the path by itself. Anyway now it's working on remote, but not on local...I can't understand why, in both cases the Slim 4 app run in a sub-directory.

Comment: The BasePathMiddleware should detect the correct basePath for both systems (dev, prod). I guess there is somewhere another `.htaccess` file from wordpress that makes trouble on your prod server.